# Heroku | Cloud Implementation

Tags: java, angular, heroku, cloud

I´m trying to put my program in Heroku, i´ve made all the steps, created a git repository, commited all the stuff, but when I try to push to heroku, I always have this output:

```
   **ERROR in Child compilation failed:
   undefined
   ERROR in budgets, maximum exceeded for /tmp/build_0e8fdf2b85b36f64aa8fc55074a8481a/src/app/app.component.css. Budget 10 kB was exceeded by 129 kB.**
```

I´ve searched for answers, and did this:

```
"budgets": {
    "type": "any",
    "baseline": "400kb",
    "maximumError": "25%",
    "maximumWarning": "12%"
},
```

I have tried with mb and kb instead of percentage but nothing worked...

Can somebody help me with this one?

Thanks